# re-populate form, after saving form data to serialized array Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am creating a form that I want users to be able to edit. The user will fill the form, save that form, fill the form with the next entry, save that form, etc. A clickable div is created each time the form is saved so that the user can go back and see their inputs to ensure they are correct before final submission of all forms. I've been able to save the form data doing this:

```
    var formArray = $('form#popsetForm').serializeArray();
```

My question: I would now like to fill the form back with the data in formArray when the user clicks on the div. Is there an easy command that will allow me to just provide the array as input and it will auto-fill the form? The below is not real code but what I'm hoping exists.

```
    $('form#popsetForm').populate(formArray)
```

Comment: Why do you need to re-populate the form?  Why not just hide it and re-display it if the user navigates back to view that form?

Comment: Are you actually going to provide me with insight if I explain my project to you? I'm building a tool that a user will use to upload anywhere from 1-10 entries. The form for each entry is the same. They will fill out the form with the data, click save, below the form will pop up a small div that has saved their info. Then the form will reset. They will fill it again with the next entry, save it, and another div will be created, etc. If they want to look back at a previous entry to ensure it was correctly entered, I want them to be able to click on the div which will then re-populate the form.

Comment: This seems to match the way I was interpreting your original question.  I have added an answer below, that should explain the approach of simply hiding forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if a solution already exists but something like this should work with `serializeArray`.

```
function restoreForm(form, formArray) {
  formArray.forEach(function (pair) {
    var selector = `input[name="${ pair.name }"], textarea[name="${ pair.name }"]`
    var input = $(form).find(selector)
    input.val(pair.value);
  })
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aycnx0gd/4/

Or like this for regular ol' `formData`

```
function restoreForm(form, formData) {
  for (var key of formData.keys()) {
    var selector = `input[name="${ key }"], textarea[name="${ key }"]`
    var input = $(form).find(selector)
    var newVal = formData.get(key)
    input.val(newVal);
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aycnx0gd/2/

Comment: Thanks for your help, I ended up doing something similar to this. Changed my serializeArray to Json and did the following: function repopulate(frm,data){
 $.each(data,function(k,v){
  $('[name='+k+']',frm).val(v);
 });
}

Answer (score 1):

I would consider simply hiding the form from view, eliminating the need to repopulate it at all.

Your form submit handler might look something like this:

```
$('#some_common_parent_element_to_all_forms').on('submit', 'form', function() {

    var $currentForm = $(this);

    // not shown - your form submit logic here

    // on success of form submittal execute following...

    // hide submitted form
    $currentForm.hide();

    // was form submitted previously?
    // if so, we don't want to generate a new form
    if($currentForm.data('submitted') !== true) {

        // clone form
        var $newForm = $currentForm.clone();

        // reset cloned form
        $newForm.get(0).reset();

        // mark submitted form as submitted
        $currentForm.data('submitted', true);


        // append new form to DOM
        $('#some_common_parent_element_to_all_forms').append($newForm).show();

        // create new div to be able to "navigate" to submitted form
        var $formNavContainer = $('#some_element_that_holds_nav_divs');
        var currentNavCount =
            $formNavContainer.find('.form_navigation').length;
        var formDisplayNum = currentNavCount + 1;
        var $newNav =
            $('<div class="form_navigation">Form ' + formDisplayNum + '</div>');
        $newNav.data('target-form-index', currentNavCount);
        $newNav.appendTo($formNavContainer);
    } else {
        // this form was previously submitted
        // perhaps we just reveal most recently created form
        $('#some_common_parent_element_to_all_forms form').last().show();
    }
}
```

And a click handler for navigation divs may look like:

```
$('#some_element_that_holds_nav_divs').on('click', '.form_navigation', function() {
    var $clickedNav = $(this);
    var formIndex = $clickedNav.data('target-form-index');

    var $allForms = $('#some_common_parent_element_to_all_forms form');
    var $selectedForm = $allForms.get(formIndex);

    $allForms.hide();
    $selectedForm.show();
});
```

This approach will allow you to create X number of forms, each storing their own set of form data. "Navigating" between forms then simply becomes a matter of showing/hiding the individual forms.